# CloudTable.Execute(TableOperation) is missing. Am I using the wrong NuGet package?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I am writing an azure function that communicates with and manipulates my Azure table. However, the CloudTable.Execute function is missing, and I cannot find a way around it. I've installed the recommended packages:

- WindowsAzure.Storage v9.1.0
- Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage v7.1.0
- Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common v9.0.0.1
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager v3.2.3.

Here are my using statements:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Azure;
//using Microsoft.Azure.Storage; ->Commented this out, not sure if I need it
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
```

And here is my code

```
public SickCity GetRow(CloudTable table, string city, string state)
{
    TableOperation tOP = TableOperation.Retrieve<SickCity>(city, state);
    TableResult result = table.Execute(tOP); //Execute(TableOperation) not found
    return result.Result as SickCity;
}
```

The only Execute functions available are the ExecuteAsync, ExecuteBatchAsync, ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync, and ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<>. Am I missing something?

Edit: I should point out that the Execute function doesn't even show in the IntelliSense

Comment: From where did you get the idea that such method exists?

Comment: I've looked up plenty of examples on working with Azure tables before I started writing my function. The most commonly used functions are table.Execute and table.ExecuteQuery

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto it's right here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.execute?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_CloudTable_Execute_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_TableOperation_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_Table_TableRequestOptions_Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage_OperationContext_

Comment: Which Azure Function runtime are you running on? v1 .NET full or v2  .NET standard? CSX script or precompiled C#? Azure Functions SDK version?

Comment: I'm using C# and NET standard 2.0. As for the runtime, I'm not sure where to find that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're not missing anything... from now on, the classical approach (not using cosmos, and even using cosmos, i think it's also this way), all the operations on the SDK seem to be async... thats all... i ran into the same surprise last night...

Comment: i'm not 100% sure, but i think they're safe to call the `Wait()` and not get a deadlock on that SDK...

Comment: Trying it now, we'll see how it goes

Answer (score 0):

Azure Function SDK package is already referencing a version of `WindowsAzure.Storage` package. Depending on your runtime version it's going to be version `7.2` or `8.6`.

So, you should only reference `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` package and use whatever version is referenced with it. Otherwise you might get cryptic runtime errors similar to yours.

Solution: remove the explicit reference to `WindowsAzure.Storage` and all other packages that are implicitly referenced by Functions SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're initializing CloudTable object. Below is the code which works fine for me in my applications:-

```
CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(<<connection string>>);
CloudTableClient tableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(<<azure table name>>);

TableOperation retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve<SickCity>(city, state);
TableResult retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation);
```

Hope this might help.